# Python socket.accept() doesn't work on second call

Tags: python, sockets

So I have the following code snippet running on a separate thread:

```
#Starts listening at the defined port on a separate thread. Terminates when 'stop' is received.
def start(self):
    try:
        if not self.is_running:
            self.is_running = True
            while self.is_running:
                self.socket.listen(1)
                conn, addr = self.socket.accept() 
                #Messages are split with $ symbol to indicate end of command in the stream.
                jStrs = [jStr for jStr in conn.recv(self.buffer_size).decode().split('$') if jStr != '']

                DoSomethingWith(jStrs)

    except Exception as ex:
        raise SystemExit(f"Server raised error: {ex}")
```

On the sender part I have something like this:

```
#Sends a string message to the desired socket.
#@param message: The string message to send.
def send(self, message):
    if not self.connected:
        self.connect()
    self.socket.send(message.encode())
    #self.close()
    #self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

What I send over the socket and how I use it does not seem relevant to the problem so I left it out for clarity. When I use my send method the first time everything is ok and works as intended. Debugger runs through the whole While routine and stops at self.socket.accept(). When I do the same send after say time.sleep(2) nothing happens. My send method doesn't block though I checked.

Notice the commented lines in the sender. When I close the connection and construct a new socket after every send I don't have this issue, but why?

When I do both sends right one after the other without any time between both will arrive at once which is expected behaviour. Why does my self.socket.accept() never get called a second time if there is a time period between the two calls (even as small as the time it takes to print something)?

Comment: Works by definition. You need to make a loop with `conn.recv` calls - receive everything from accepted client, until the socket is closed.

Comment: Move the listen outside the loop. Create the client socket before you try to send anything. Strange code.

Comment: The second code is just a method of a larger class which constructs the socket and everything. I left out all of those chunks of code for clarity because I thought people will assume that the socket is created since I'm using self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue thanks to @Alex F from the comments. It seems that I executed the loop in the wrong place. You don't want to loop self.socket.accept() but the conn.recv() part once the socket is accepted. Simply moving the while loop below self.socket.accept() worked for me.

```
#Starts listening at the defined port on a separate thread. Terminates when 'stop' is received.
def start(self):
    try:
        if not self.is_running:
            self.is_running = True
            self.socket.listen(1)
                                    #<---- moved from here
            conn, addr = self.socket.accept() 

            while self.is_running:  #<---- to here
                #Messages are split with $ symbol to indicate end of command in the stream.
                jStrs = [jStr for jStr in conn.recv(self.buffer_size).decode().split('$') if jStr != '']
            
                #Loads the arguments and passes them to the remotes dictionary
                #which holds all the methods
                for jStr in jStrs: 
                    jObj = json.loads(jStr)
                    func_name = jObj["name"]
                    del jObj["name"]
                    remote.all[func_name](**jObj)

    except Exception as ex:
        raise SystemExit(f"Server raised error: {ex}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your socket object once, then send messages across it.

```
sender = socket.socket()

def send(sender, message):
    if not sender.connected:
        sender.connect()
    sender.send(message.encode())
```

You could wrap this in a class with an **init** if need be.
https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/introduction

Comment: It is not visible from the snippet of code I presented but the sender socket is already created inside a class once upon construction. I always use the same socket in the example

Comment: kay.  Saw that one line commented out, and mentioned possibly making a new one each time.  Thought you were struggling w/ that.